# extract uppercase words from string

Tags: python

I want to extract all the words that are complete in uppercase (so not only the first letter, but all the letters in the word) from strings in columnY in dataset X

I have the following script:

```
X['uppercase'] = X['columnY'].str.extract('([A-Z][A-Z]+)')
```

But that only extract the first uppercased word in the string.

Then I tried extractall:

```
X['uppercase'] = X['columnY'].str.extractall('([A-Z][A-Z]+)')
```

But I got the following error:

TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the actual output you want here?  Do you want a _single_ column with space separated uppercase words, or _multiple_ columns, one for each uppercase word (or something else) ?

Comment: Both is ok, but I prefer one column with all the uppercase words (space separated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use regular expressions and list comprehensions as below

```
import re

def extract_uppercase_words(text):
    return re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+\b', text)

X['columnY'].apply(extract_uppercase_words)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
X['uppercase'] = X['columnY'].str.findall('\b[A-Z]+\b')
```

This will give you a list of all the UPPERCASE words.
And If you want all these words to be concatenated in a single string you can use the below code.

```
X['uppercase'] = X['columnY'].str.findall('\b[A-Z]+\b').str.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you *only* have words in the column, you could try:

```py
X["uppercase"] = X["columnY"].str.replace(r'\s*\b\w*[a-z]\w*\b\s*', ' ', regex=True)
                             .str.replace(r'\s{2,}', ' ', regex=True)
                             .str.strip()
```

The first replacement targets non all uppercase words (being defined as any word with at least one *lowercase* letter), as well as any surrounding spaces.  We replace with just a single space.  The second replacement targets any excess spaces and replaces with just a single space.

Comment: Perhaps add some explanation about the technique?

Comment: I have edited my question, because I only need the words that are completely uppercased. So, not the word 'Dog', but the word 'DOG'.